# Cannot set signing config storeFile after installing Android Studio 3.6 & updating Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have my signing config set up so the Keystore & properties are stored outside of my android repository. In my `build.gradle` I have them setup like so:

```
def userHome = System.getProperty['user.home']
def keystorePropertiesFile = new File(userHome, ".android/keystore.properties")
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

signingConfigs {
    myApp {
        storeFile = new File(userHome, keystoreProperties['KEYSTORE'])
        ...
    }
}
```

This has been working for years. Now, after updating to Android studio 3.6.3 & letting it update my Gradle version to 5.6.4 and the Gradle Android plugin version to 3.6.3, I get the following error when building (Gradle sync works fine):

> Cannot cast object 'property(interface org.gradle.api.file.Directory, undefined)' with class 'org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$DefaultDirectoryVar' to class 'java.io.File'

Even if I simply hard-code the path to `storeFile` (`storeFile file("/path/to/keystore/file")`) I get the same error. If I comment out just the `storeFile` assignment, everything is fine.

I've spent the last several hours trying to find any relevant information on this, but all I"ve been able to find is that what I'm doing should be correct.

Does anyone have any idea what changed & how I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried `userHome.toFile()` or `userHome.toPath()`?

Comment: Both `.toFile()` and `.toPath()` give me: `No signature of method: java.lang.String.toPath() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
  Possible solutions: toSet(), length(), toURL(), toURL(), toFloat(), toList()`